# Force web pages to extend wrap to full screen browser window width on PC - from tiny column in middle - firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, window, rendering

Web pages are not wrapping to the width of my 24" monitor in Firefox (up to date).  Same in troubleshoot mode.
Sites include Facebook, telegram, google search, many news sites, and even Firefox reader view. Even Firefox settings pages are wrapped to a narrow column.  Sample screenshots below, plus Edge sample - same problem.

The problem occurs at 100% zoom, and worsens at 67% which is my preferred zoom.

Does anyone know an add-on or procedure that will fix this? (If possible, something simple for people who cannot write code? But otherwise, anything, with instructions?)

(I found one add-on that looks like it does what I want in 1 URL, but that URL redirects, so it is not possible to test):  [Maximize Telegram Web – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-US)](https://addons.mozilla.org/eu/firefox/addon/maximize-telegram-web/)

[image: Maximize Telegram Web]

[image: reader view]
[image: telegram]
[image: google search]
[image: facebook]
[image: random web sites]
[image: superuser not so bad but still not perfect]
[image: even ff settings page is wrapped to a narrow column!]
[image: google search in edge]

Comment: Does this happen in Microsoft Edge or Chrome? Or in [Firefox in Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems#w_start-firefox-in-safe-mode)?

Comment: @harrymc
Does this not happen in your Firefox browser, edge or chrome?

Comment: No, it's unique to your computer. The above tests are to try and narrow the problem range.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for that insight.  I have updated my question with the answer to your question (=yes), and also an addon which I found which appears to do what I want, but only on 1 URL.

BTW, I recall the same problem occurring, at least with Google search and FF settinga pages, on my previous laptop on Windows 8.1. (Current OS is w10)

Comment: Is the answer that this also happens in Microsoft Edge/Chrome and also in Firefox in Safe Mode?

Comment: @harrymc yes (assuming FF troubleshooting mode is "safe mode")

Comment: @harrymc WHY ARE YOU TELLING ME TO ZOOM THE PAGE??? That does not answer my question, +it is all through the google search results, if I had wanted it.

Comment: @harrymc just to clarify -you are saying that in Firefox on your PC, google search results list, and about:preferences, both wrap to the full width of a maximised window on a standard monitor, at 100% zoom?

Comment: No, they have and always had their maximal width, but not as extreme as in your pictures.